# Get number of records n a group in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I wrote a LINQ query that it' result similar to this :

```
var res = from a  in tbl
          group a by {a.StateCode,a.CityCode} into grp
          //where grp.Count() == 1
          select ...

StateCode       CityCode           ......
------------------------------------------
01               001               ......
01               002               ......
02               001               ......
03               001               ......
03               002               ......
03               003               ......
```

indeed I want to get just `02       001` record because it has one result row in the  final result.If I add commented code It returns count of records correspond to each group not count of own group.I know I can do this with two `group by` but is there a better way to get row that has (for example) one row in the result?

Comment: Isn't that you want the `02 001` because the `02` is present only once in the `StateCode`? If so you just need to `group by StateCode`, and select just 1 from the groups of 1 element, because there may be more groups of 1 element, in your example, it's just `02`.

Comment: Yes there is more than `02`. the problem is I want to get `02` and `001` for state `02`. with group by I can get one of them and count of other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
(from b in Tbls
where (from a in Tbls
       where a.StateCode == b.StateCode
       group a by a.StateCode into grp
       where grp.Count () == 1
       select grp).Count() > 0
select b).Dump();
```

Here's the SQL I used to test it with:

```
create table tbl (StateCode varchar(5), CityCode varchar(5))

insert tbl values ('01', '001')
insert tbl values ('01', '002')
insert tbl values ('02', '001')
insert tbl values ('03', '001')
insert tbl values ('03', '002')
insert tbl values ('03', '003')
```

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake

Comment: That definitely works but what are you trying to select? You can do ``select grp`` but not ``select a``. If you need to select the whole row, you will need a more complex query.

Comment: Serves me right for not reading carefully. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did you test it? it does not return any thing

Comment: It did work on a table I thought was similar to your example but after reading your question and the comments yet another time, I'm still not entirely clear what you are asking. If my latest update isn't correct, I'll just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by StateCode **and** CityCode so each group has only one element. You must group by StateCode only and inlcude `where grp.Count() == 1` again.

Each group contains the StateCode as its key and an enumeration of the elements. Since you already filtered for groups with only a a single element you can just return the first of each group:

```
var res = from a in tbl
          group a by a.StateCode into grp
          where grp.Count() == 1
          select grp.FirstOrDefault();
```